# Get memory locations using IDAPython

Tags: ida, idapython

In my code, I am using `idc.GetOpnd(ea,0)` and `idc.GetOpnd(ea,1)` to get the 2 operands of an instruction. However, if its a `call` (or `jmp`) instruction, I am getting symbols like `_perror` and `loc_8083BA9`.

Using IDAPython, is it possible to remove all the symbols and deal only with memory locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GetOperandValue instead of GetOpnd to get the memory location.

```
Python>GetOpnd(0xb77a2d99,0)
__Unwind_Resume
Python>'%x'%(GetOperandValue(0xb77a2d99,0))
b76fc24e
```